# Is it possible to include features like match_phrase_prefix and slop in Percolated Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I would like to know whether match_phrase_prefix and slop search options can be used along with ES Percolated query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it because it support storing Elastic DSL query.

You can read my blog on percolate query [here](https://medium.com/@psajan106/elasticsearch-percolate-query-2f689732aa15) which will give you basic understanding with real life example.